# Can I use Chrome Debugger with a live Website and local overrides?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a live website that I don't own the code with Chromes [Local overrides](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools) and the VS Code extension. I can't get it to work. Can I only connect to localhost? How can I get this to work?

I tried two configs:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to url with files served from ./out",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 443,
            "url": "https://notmysite.com/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/"
        }
    ]
}
```

With launching Chrome like this:`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222`

And I tried launching with this config:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch External Site",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://notmysite.com",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just found this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codemooseus.vscode-devtools-for-chrome and this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-edge-devtools

Comment: have you managed to configure VS Code for local overrides on a live website?

Comment: No ended up using Chrome DEV Tools.